# Get data from database c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I created a simple project to get the most out of the databases and tables. I added to the project with `Menu->Project->Add New Item->Service-based Database` a `Users.mdf` database, in which I created the table `Users`. I searched on multiple threads how to acces the database but none worked so far. My code right now looks like this ( I got the code from a youtube tutorial), basically when I will click a button I'd expect a `dataGridView` to be filled.

```
private void show_database_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring ="Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Database=Users.mdf;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(" select * from Users.Users;", conDataBase);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
        DataTable dbadataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbadataset);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        bSource.DataSource = dbadataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dbadataset);

    }
```

And when I click the button I get an :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

What am I doing wrong here? ( to be mentioned that I am on a proxy connection, dont know if that is something to bother).

Comment: The problem is with your connection string. Could you please cross check the connection string?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @un-lucky That was the first problem, i got the connection string using `Database->(right click)Properties->Connection String (copy)` . Now I get another error with `An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ...`

Comment: And adding `User Interface = True` isn't accepted

Comment: @un-lucky you can add your comment as an answer because it did solved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A network-related or instance-specific error` will occur when The user failed to authenticate to the specified server. Or The specified server is not found or unavailable. In your case please cross check the connection string for the proper authentication as well as the server. fixing issues with connectionString will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your connection string is incorrect.

an easy way to build a connection sting is

1. create a new text document and call it "connection.udl" ( the extension is important)
2. double click the connection.udl file
3. a "Data Link Properties" dialog will open.
4. fill in all the details for the database you want to connect to.
5. test that you have got it correct by clicking the test button.
6. open the connection.udl file with notepad
7. the third line is the connection string, copy this and paste it into your code

note you may have issue creating the connection.udl file if your file explorer is set to hide extensions for known file types if so switch this off.

Comment: An easier approach which I found is to go to `Server Explorer`, right-click on the database, click on `Properties` and there is a field `Connection String` :)

Answer (score -1):

First check whether the SQL SERVER instance name is correctly mentioned in the connection string .. if that does not work try restarting the sql service. (it has helped me once)

Comment: do you think that this is an answer?